# ubuntu-12.04-wubi-i386.tar.xz for the wubi installer

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, wubi

I ran the wubi installer (from an extracted ubuntu ISO) and it downloads `ubuntu-12.04-wubi-i386.tar.xz` but it's slow and non-resumable so I cancelled it, found a mirror of the file online and downloaded it using *Intenet download manager*.  Where should I be placing `ubuntu-12.04-wubi-i386.tar.xz` file so the wubi installer won't have to download that file anymore? Thank you.

**Update:** I extracted the archive and there are two files, I'm afraid I do not know where to place them.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell Wubi where the file is. Run `wubi.exe` as follows from the command line (e.g. if you placed the image in a folder called `C:\UbuntuImage`):

```
wubi.exe --dimagepath=C:\UbuntuImage\ubuntu-12.04-wubi-i386.tar.xz
```

Don't extract the contents before running.

PS I found it tripped over paths with spaces in them; if you find the same problem then move it to a folder as shown above.

**Additional info**

You can only install Ubuntu (32bit or 64bit) using the diskimage as shown above. If you want to install Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Edubuntu or Mythbuntu (or Xubuntu only on releases prior to 12.10) then you need to download the Desktop CD ISO and save it in the same folder as `wubi.exe` before running Wubi. Make sure that the ISO matches the release of `wubi.exe` and the flavour you are installing.

Note that Wubi will check the ISO MD5 sum to ensure integrity (if you run it when connected to the internet). It will still use the downloaded ISO if it's valid. However, if you disconnect from the internet it only checks the kernel and initrd md5sums so you should always check the ISO yourself.

Comment: hi, i just read your answer. I will definitely try and will update you later. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just want you to know that it worked like a charm, now I can install and run Ubuntu :) Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic dual boot for the Windows 8  or system based in i386, the answer is the same :

1. download `wubi.exe` that you wish, and the `i386.tar`  and `i386.iso` files.
2. Open system terminal window (like ms-dos window)
3. Go to the folder using cd folder command and put

   ```
   wubi.exe --dimagepath=C:\UbuntuImage\ubuntu-1X.XX.XX-wubi-i386.tar.xz
   ```

   (the XX.XX.XX is the verion of ubuntu)
4. Select in the ubuntu window your disk patition, name and password.
5. and Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you want, but don't even bother with wubi. The ubuntu-in-windows is gonna take hdd space anyways, so you may as well install it on a proper partition instead of using wubi and risking windows messing it up. The Ubuntu Installer is very good, I find, and even setting up a dual boot is pretty painless with their installer.