# Wubi without downloading ubuntu-12.04.1-wubi-i386.tar.xz

Tags: wubi

I have a class of computational physics. I want to install Ubuntu on 24 systems,
unfortunately our access to the internet is limited.

On the other hand I do not like to make new partitions for Linux. So I have to use Wubi but Wubi needs a large file i.e: "ubuntu-12.04.1-wubi-i386.tar.xz".

Unfortunately I could not make a transition to Wubi because when I put "ubuntu-12.04.1-wubi-i386.tar.xz" manually in the Ubuntu/disks directory, Wubi starts to complain about the existence of already installed ubuntu and all thing should be done from scratch.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Save it in another folder and install it as described here: http://askubuntu.com/q/143463/14916

Answer (score 0):

Use an install disk to do this. Download the iso from [ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com), burn it to a CD, take the CD with you to the school and install it under Windows. This is all.