# Is there a version of the wubi installer that can be used offline?

Tags: wubi, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ubuntu-12.04-wubi-i386.tar.xz  for the wubi installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143463/ubuntu-12-04-wubi-i386-tar-xz-for-the-wubi-installer)

I have a PC with Windows currently running on it with no internet connection, and I'd like to try Ubuntu on it without creating or modifying partitions. However, I see that the wubi installer download is ~2.4MB, which is far smaller than an Ubuntu iso. Is there any way of achieving a wubi or similar install on the PC in question without connecting it to the internet? (I have other computers with internet connections fr downloading files, etc)

Thanks for taking your time to read this.

Comment: You still have to download things off the internet, a)download a full ubuntu iso, mount it b)download the ubuntu iso and place it in the same folder with wubi, run wubi.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the WUBI installer only works when you are connected to the internet.  Once you start it the installer will automatically download the operating system.  I just did it two nights ago and it was a surprisingly painless process. The only downside is that the installation is limited to 30GB. More then enough to get to better know Ubuntu.

If you wish to do several computers then you might want to just download the DVD and do it that way. I am not sure about the most recent versions but in the past I am believe there was an option to install Ubuntu 'alongside' Windows. Installation that way is pretty easy too barring hardware incompatibilities.

Comment: It works offline, provided you download the correct ISO or the diskimage first.

Comment: @bcbc I recommend posting this as an answer (unless you know of a previous question about offline Wubi installation, in which case I recommend flagging this question to be closed as a duplicate of it).

Comment: @EliahKagan good idea - I've added a link to installing offline with the diskimage which works only with Ubuntu; using the ISO is another approach which will also work with Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Edubuntu and Mythbuntu.