# Wubi installer stuck on "Downloading ubunt-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz"

Tags: installation, wubi

I downloaded and mounted the iso to install the 64 bit wubi, but every time I run it it gets stuck on "Downloading ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz . I've seen other people with this problem who never seem to get it solved.

I'm running on a 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium machine, my internet connection is fine, I'm just not sure what the problem is or how to fix it.

Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: How long have you been waiting? It usually takes a *long* time.

Comment: There is a [bug in Wubi 12.04.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1134770) that cannot use the ISO (you shouldn't mount it either but that won't help because of the bug). Therefore there is no point in downloading it. Wubi.exe must instead download the diskimage (500MB) so that will take some time. You can manually download it, but the it requires a `--dimagepath=` argument to find it as explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143463/ubuntu-12-04-wubi-i386-tar-xz-for-the-wubi-installer)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug on 12.04.02 64bit. Try using 12.04.01 instead and do an upgrade to get to 12.10.
Also, do not mount the ISO.  There is no need, it will just cause problems...

Answer (score 1):

Please wait for sometime, it may take some time i waited on ubuntu 12.04.1 it is done you can get it on http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/releases//precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso this is 32 bit  and http://ubuntu-releases.mirror.net.in/releases//precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso is 64 bit as per your requirements. Don't be confused, first link is ubuntu 12.04.1 lts 32 bit and second one is ubuntu 12.04.1 lts is 64 bit. lts stands for long term support