# Wubi offline installation error; failed

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi, 64-bit, offline

I'd read a guide to install Ubuntu using wubi offlinely, but it's failed. Wubi installer is exact at root folder of Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS desktop ISO file. This is some string on log file:

```
04-15 12:34 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO E:\Download\Virtual Drives\ubuntu-precise-LTS-wubi-amd64\ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
04-15 12:34 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain casper\vmlinuz
```

Yes I exactly place ISO file at that directory, but still failed (till now).

What should I do?

Comment: Check the md5 hash of the iso. Probably a corrupt download.

Comment: Nope, it works while burning it to LiveCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an existing bug: [Wubi fails to detect 12.04.2 and 13.04 AMD64 ISO](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1134770). There is no workaround other than waiting for my patch to be accepted - basically you cannot install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu using Wubi with the ISO (online or offline).

If you run `wubi.exe` 12.04.2 standalone (no ISO) it will work by downloading the disk image or if you download the disk image yourself you can then install it offline provided you pass the `--dimagepath=<path to disk image>` argument to `wubi.exe` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/143478/14916)

Comment: An bug... I'll try to download to make sure it works :)

Comment: Great! Note that my patch has been accepted and a new Wubi.exe has been built yesterday for 12.04.2 (but not yet released). You can find the most recent 12.04 `wubi-rnnn.exe` here: http://people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/